# c++ crashes the run every time i try running this section of the code

Tags: c++

it started crashing once i added the function differentiate and called it in the main method. the code was running fine before i added this method. the code is supposed to provide a execute a polynomial then find the derivative for it using arrays for the polynomials.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int readPolynomial (int maxOrder, double polynomial[]) {
     int order,i;
    cout<< "enter the order of the polynomial";
    cin>>order;
    i=order;
    while (i>-1){
        cout<<" enter a coeffecient for x^"<<i<<endl;
        cin>>polynomial[i];
        --i;
    }
    return order;
}

void displayPolynomial (int order, double polynomial[]) {
    for (int i = order; i>-1;i--){
        if (polynomial[i] > 0) {
                 cout << " +" << polynomial[i]<< "x^"<<i;       
        } 
        else {
            cout << " - " << fabs(polynomial[i])<<"x^"<<i;
        } 
    }
}
int differentiate (int order, double polynomial[], double derivative[]){
    int der;
    der= order-1;
    int i = der;
    while (i>-1){
        derivative[i]=polynomial[order]*order;
        order--;
        i--;
    }
    return der; 
}
int main () {

    const int MAXN = 8; // maximum order (a constant)
    double polynomial[MAXN + 1];
    int polynomialN;
    double x,value;
    double derivative[polynomialN-1];
    double derOrder;

    polynomialN = readPolynomial (MAXN, polynomial);
    cout << "\nThe polynomial (order = " << polynomialN << ") is\n";
    displayPolynomial (polynomialN, polynomial);
    derOrder = differentiate (polynomialN, polynomial, derivative);

    cout<< " the derivative of the polynomial is:"<<endl;
    displayPolynomial (derOrder, derivative);

    system("PAUSE"); return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the **desired behavior, a specific problem or error** and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also try memory checking tools (AddressSanitizer, Valgrind).

Comment: `double derivative[polynomialN-1];`  - Um. what is `polynomialN` at the *exact* point that declaration is encountered? Hint: the array doesn't magically expand just because you later change the value of `polynomialN`.

Comment: You use polynomialN before it is initialized.  Bad things will happen.